# How to place my footer?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem, i'm just a beginner and i would like to improve my CSS and HTML skills, so if you have some tips please post it here,
so my problem is about my footer, it is not on the right place, (on bottom, center of the page)
so someone help me please?

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <p id="nome">João Pedro</p>
            <a href="mailto:jp_5_5@hotmail.fr"><p id="email">jp_5_5@hotmail.fr</p></a>
            <p id="imagem"><img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t1.0-9/10250173_10203771744604525_8177123278861015451_n.jpg" style="width: 50px;
    height: 50px" /></p>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <p>Nome</p>
            <hr>
            <p>Email</p>
            <hr>
            <p>Contacto</p>
            <hr>
            <p>Sobre</p>
            <hr>
            <p>Mais</p>
            <hr>
            <p>Jogos</p>
            <hr>
            <p>Videos</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p id=boss><img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/s720x720/564356_10200810585497398_1364591551_n.jpg" style="height: 300px"/></p>
            <div id="texto"><h3>O que é o Jejum de Jesus? -Vocês perguntam.</h3>
            <p>O Jejum de Jesus é onde nós nos santificamos a Deus para receber o Espirito Santo.</p>
            <p>Durante 40 dias iremos nos desapegar das coisas mundanas tais como:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Internet</li>
                <li>Musica</li>
                <li>Jogos</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my css:

```
body {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#header {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    width: 98%;
    background-color: #230f65;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 14px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #bdabf8;
    width: 10%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 14px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #dfd7f7;
    width: 86%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    border: 1px solid black;    
}

.left {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #230f65;
    width: 85%;
}

#nome {
    color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family: sans-serif, Verdana;
}

#email {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif, Verdana;
    color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

p > img {
    border-radius: 100%;
}

#imagem {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 140px;
}

#boss {
    padding-top: 33px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

#texto {
    padding-left: 255px;
}
```

Comment: Nice way to mock someone's English.

Comment: Would anyone care for a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/TT3s8/

Comment: Add some content in your footer such as your site name, or copy right statement and it will start displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `height` for your footer, as it (yet) has not content and thus no height.

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #230f65;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

If you want your footer to stick to the bottom, take a look at http://cssstickyfooter.com

Also, to center the footer, in  this case use `left: 7.5%;`, which is have the remaining space on the sides of the footer. (100% - 85% equals 15%, half of it on the left, half on the right)

Comment: Thanks!!! it worked
and just one more question, what if i wanted to put "clear: both;" ? i tried but it doesnt stay at the bottom

Comment: nice one, i checked now the website and it was useful :D

Comment: but i have another question, why my footer isnt on the center of the page? it's on the right side

Comment: omg thank you so much, it's perfect now, but how did you know the remaining space? so I can do it by myself every time i need it

Comment: @user3779775 indeed ;)